# Create a pair matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a question about creating an $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix, in which you can compare all elements of an vector.

For example:

I have 3 lists with 4 which includes in each of them 4 elements:

```
{{3, 8, 9, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 9},{4, 6, 10, 1}}
```

Call the first element of an vector is $R_1$, the second $ R_2 $, the third $ R_3 $, and the fourth $ R_4 $.

Now I want to check which element each list is smaller than other elements in the **same** list. For example:

$ 3<8,\, 3<9,\, 3<2,\, 8<9,\, 8 \nless 2, 9 \nless 8 \ldots $

I want a $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix containing how often $ R_1 $ is smaller than $ R_2 $, or $ R_2 $ smaller than $ R_3 $, et c.

http://cewebs.cs.univie.ac.at/topics/RisikoManagement/index.php?m=F&t=info&c=aresource&CEWebS_type=image&CEWebS_file=Abb4_14.JPG&CEWebS_what=Doppelter~32~paarweiser~32~Vergleich&CEWebS_rev=2

But there could be a 5th element in a list, or $ n $ lists.

(Mathematica Version 9.0)

Comment: For the first part: `(Less @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ {{3, 8, 9, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 9}, {4, 6, 10, 1}}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
lsts = {{3, 8, 9, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 9}, {4, 6, 10, 1}}
cmp[lst_] := Outer[Boole[#1 < #2] &, lst, lst]   (* edit: use Boole *)
Total[cmp /@ lsts]
```

Comment: Use `Boole[#1 < #2] &` instead of `If[#1 < #2, 1, 0] &`.

Comment: @J.M. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = {{3, 8, 9, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 9}, {4, 6, 10, 1}};

pos = Transpose[{#, Reverse[#, 2]}] &[Subsets[Range[sz = Length[First[L]]], {2}]];

MatrixForm[SparseArray[Rule @@@ DeleteCases[Tally[Catenate[
      MapThread[Part, {pos, Transpose[Map[-Sign[Subtract @@@
           Subsets[#, {2}]] &, L]]}]]], {List, _}], {sz, sz}]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: I dont have the Catenate function...

Comment: but this looks right

Comment: @Mudy, then please edit your question to say what version you are using.